# Multiple value field create duplicate results when using leftJoin

Tags: 8, database

I have a query to the database for a specific content type. Everything is working as expected but when I add a leftJoin query on the field 'node__field_country' which is a taxonomy term reference field and a multiple value field, the query results of the other field is duplicated or triplicated depending on how many value the multiple value field has.

```php
$connection = Database::getConnection();
$connection->query("SET SESSION sql_mode = ''")->execute();

$query = $connection->select('node_field_data', 'n');
$query->condition('n.type', 'page');
$query->condition('n.status', '1');
$query->fields('n', ['title', 'nid']);
$query->condition('n.langcode', 'en');

$query->leftJoin('node__field_report_date', 'report_date', 'report_date.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->fields('report_date', ['field_report_date_value']);

$query->leftJoin('node__field_number_of_male', 'male', 'male.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->addExpression('SUM(field_number_of_male_value)', 'male_count');

// The query below is the reason for duplication but i need this on my result
$query->leftJoin('node__field_country', 'country', 'country.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->leftJoin('taxonomy_term_field_data', 'country_term', 'country_term.tid = country.field_country_target_id');
$query->fields('country_term', ['name']);
$query->addExpression("group_concat(DISTINCT country_term.name)", "country_origin");

$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
return $results;
```

If the sum of 'number_of_male' is 10 (without the query for the country) and the 'country' field has a multiple value of Canada, Australia, Somalia. Then the result of this query will display '30' as the sum of 'number_of_male'.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to correct this result?